# Finding a function that satisfies $f(y)-f(x)=x/y-1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I want to find all (differentiable) functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ that satisfies
$$f(y)-f(x)=\frac{x}{y}-1$$

My approach was taking $y=x+d$, so that I can have
$$f(x+d)-f(x)=\frac{x}{x+d}-1=-\frac{d}{x+d}.$$
If I devide both sides with $d$ and then take $d\rightarrow 0$, I should have

$$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x}, $$

which implies $f(x)=ln ~x+C$ for some constant $C$. However, if I plug in $x$ and $y$ back to the derived $f(x)$, I cannot have $f(y)-f(x)=\frac{x}{y}-1$.. Can anyone identify the mistake in my derivation or anyone knows how to derive such $f$?

Comment: $\frac x y$ is not defined when $y=0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Okay. I'll have to assume $f:(0,1)\rightarrow(0,1)$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Such a function does not exist and in fact you just proved that. Another way to see this is to swap $x$ and $y$. Namely $$ x/y-1=f(x)-f(y)=-(f(y)-f(x))=-y/x+1.$$ Hence one would get for all $x,y\in (0,1)$ $$x/y+y/x=2,$$ which is not true (pick for example $x=1/2$ and $y=1/4$).

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks!

Comment: $\left(\frac{x}{y} -1\right)^2 \ge 0 \implies \frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}\ge 2$ with equality iff $x=y\not=0$, so the domain of the function would have to be restricted to a single non-zero point

Comment: @Henry Nice observation!

Comment: Or consider $f(y)-f(1)=1/y-1\implies f(y)=f(1)-1+1/y$  but $f(1)-f(x)=x-1\implies f(x)=f(1)+1-x\implies f(y)=f(1)+1-y.$

Answer (score 3):

Just plug $x=0$ in the equation.

You get $f(y)=f(0)-1=cst$ for all $y\in[0,1]$.

But clearly $f$ cannot be a constant function as for instance for $y=1$ then $f(x)=f(1)+1-x$ is not constant.

Notice that even $f(y)-g(x)=\dfrac xy-1$ with two independent functions $f,g$ is not possible.

Indeed $f(y)-g(y)=0$ for all $y$ therefore $f=g$ and we are back to square one.